# Convert jqgrid data to lowercase while displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, lowercase, formatter

I am displaying the data from database using the JQGRID to the user and I have an field EMAIL in which I want to display all the data in lowercase even though the email data stored in DB is uppercase.
I tried using the formatter and its throwing me some error

```
Uncaught TypeError: cellvalue.toLowerCase is not a function
```

Following is the jqgrid code which I am using to load the email.

```
{
    name: "EMAIL_ID",
    align: "center",
    width: 140,
    formatter: case_converter,
    search: true
},
```

following is the Formatter function I am using to convert the data into lowercase for that particular cell value.

```
//Convert Email Id to lowecase
function case_converter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
{
    var email_lower = cellvalue.toLowerCase();
    console.log(email_lower);
    return email_lower;

}
```

Even though I am using the  Standard javascript function I am getting this error.

Comment: Log out `cellvalue`, chances are it's not a string. Might also be worth considering using CSS to perform the case conversion with `text-transform: lowercase`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check if this is a string as commented before

```
//Convert Email Id to lowecase
function case_converter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
{
    return typeof cellvalue === 'string' ? cellvalue.toLowerCase() : cellvalue;
}
```